# Excluding certain windows from screen capture

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to capture the entire desktop with `BitBlt` and I also want to exclude certain windows (of my own application) from the capture. I can set `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute to them, but it wouldn’t work in Window 7 with desktop composition enabled. Showing and hiding a window is not an option as it produces a flicker.

Comment: It's deprecated (i.e., may not work in future versions of Windows), but you can use a custom [image transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in conjunction with a [window filter list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692396%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). (The image transform merely copies the bits somewhere else for safekeeping.)

Comment: @Raymond:  That seems worthy as an answer, rather than a comment to me.  I'd upvote it.

Comment: I don't know if this will work but its simple and may be worth a try. Handle the WM_PRINT message but don't draw anything, also don't pass the message to DefWindowProc.