# Switching top-most form without flickering

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm developing a magnifier in C# .NET (using WindowsForm) that shows a top-most click-able through form. This top-most window shows an specific part of the screen.

The problem I'm having is that to take the screenshot I need to `Hide()` and `Show()` the form (otherwise I would take a screenshot of the magnifier) and this creates an annoying flickering in which the magnifier disappears and rapidly appears again.

How could I take a screenshot of the Desktop without hiding/showing the form?
Is there another approach/workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Excluding certain windows from screen capture](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8080559)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to take a screen shot of the area inside the magnifier or that you want to take a screen shot of the area under the magnifier (read non magnified area)?

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I haven't use it though. I'm sure is not what you are looking for in this question, but may be of help in your project.

Comment: Answering Nick's question: The magnifier is not an element, it is an screen-wide, top-most window. More like a whole screen zoom. The screenshot should not contain any area of this zoom window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the form's Opacity property.  Set it to 99% in the designer.  When you are ready to take the screen shot, set it to 0, make the shot and set it back to 0.99.

The change is instant, no need to wait and no flicker or repainting.  Do *not* restore it to 1.0, that flickers.

Do beware that you remove the "Hall of Mirrors" effect from the magnifier.  Bit of a loss :)

Comment: Thanks, confirmed, the change is a lot lot faster and the flickering is almost gone, practically invisible.

By the way, I didn't notice the "Hall of Mirrors" effect now "gone"... What effect did you mean?