# Full screen zooming without taking screenshots in Visual Studio C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, zooming

I would like to achieve a real and **"living" whole screen zooming** similar to the Windows 7 feature that you can see by clicking on Start>Magnifier>Views>Full-screen.

You can notice 2 things on this app:

1.- It is not an top-most Windows form application that is constantly taking screenshots and resizing it otherwise it would flicker.

2.- When the cursor is over an item, like an icon, the icon stills shows a mouse-over animation (this is what I call a "living" zoom, go on a try it over an icon).

I haven't been able to create an app with these 2 features with a Windows form that takes screenshots see my other post ([Switching top-most form without flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118054/switching-top-most-form-without-flickering)) since it flickers.

I suppose that this type of zoom is directly calling some System drawing methods. **Does someone knows how to achieve this result it C# .NET?**

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help you get started? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692402(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Taking screenshots" is a viable solution, but capturing the mouse pointer correctly, as well as visual effects (like shadows etc.), you'll need to do captures in a special way.

Additionally, bear in mind that using [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) is not advisable as it leaks graphics handles.

What you should look at is the [Magnification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that was introduced in Windows 7 and extended in Windows 8. This is what the magnification tool is using.

Comment: What I found is that taking screenshots is viable if the zoom screen is not very big, a whole screen zoom shows an almost invisible flicker that gives headaches after a few minutes. Maybe you know a faster way to take and paint screenshots on a panel? Indeed I used CopyFromScreen =/

Comment: I'm assuming that the flickering is in the mouse cursor. As I said, special precautions needs to be done to capture that.

Comment: The flickering is happening when painting the image, the cursor is not an issue actually, CopyFromScreen hides the cursor while taking the screenshot.

Comment: That's probably easy to fix, most likely you have not set the right styles on the control, like opaque, allpaintinginwmpaint, etc. Check the [Control.SetStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) method.