# How to exclude certain window from screen capture in Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to capture the desktop and exclude a window of my application of being captured.

My window is being created as follows:

```
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LAYERED,
                        g_lpszClassName, NULL, WS_THICKFRAME,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,
                        _WPModule.GetHInstance(), NULL);
```

And I capture the screen as follows:

```
HWND    hWndCapture     = ::GetDesktopWindow();
HDC     hdcScreen       = ::GetDC(hWndCapture);
HDC     hdcMem          = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

::BitBlt(
    hdcMem,
    0,
    0,
    Width, //width of region of interest
    Height, //height of region of interest
    hdcScreen,
    X, //left staring point for capture
    Y, //top staring point for capture
    SRCCOPY);
```

I have found the following link [Excluding certain windows from screen capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080559/excluding-certain-windows-from-screen-capture) but it does not give a solution for I.E 8 and onward. I did not find any other solution posted for this issue.

Comment: Clarification: what do you want instead of your window, the stuff that's "underneath" or just a black rectangle?  If the latter, you can paint black over your window(s) after you blt the desktop into your DC

Comment: A straight forward solution (if you are targeting Windows 7+ with DWM enabled) is calling [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx) on the window you wish to exclude. Specifying the `WDA_MONITOR` affinity prevents the window from being included in the screenshot.

Comment: @mark No, actually I want the first, to capture what's underneath. Sorry for not clearing this out in the begining

Comment: @IInspectable I'm targeting Windows XP and onward so is there another way to do it?

Comment: @IInspectable I have tried you suggestion, just see if it works, and it places a black rectangle instead of the window and not what's underneath so in any case this is not what I want.

Comment: Hide your window, wait a bit to give windows underneath some time to repaint themselves, capture screenshot, show your window back.

Comment: @Gidi If you have version requirements, then you should specify them. All the same, if you insist on coding for an ancient unsupported OS, you are denying yourself access to modern APIs that have more capability. At the very least, make the XP code a special case.

Comment: Any solution for topic at that moment?

Answer (score 7):

I'm aware this question is pretty old, but I ran into the same problem and it was very, very hard to find any information at all regarding this.

Since **Windows 10 version 2004** (build 10.0.19041), the `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) has been expanded to include a flag called `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE` (0x00000011). This will remove the window from images captured with `BitBlt`

> The window is displayed only on a monitor. Everywhere else, the window does not appear at all.
> One use for this affinity is for windows that show video recording controls, so that the controls are not included in the capture.

> Introduced in Windows 10 Version 2004. See remarks about compatibility regarding previous versions of Windows.

**For versions before 2004, it will use the existing `WDA_MONITOR` flag.**

I have tested this with a screen capture of the desktop and I am unsure what would happen if you were to use a window DC.

So I guess a possible solution would be:

```
// get window handle
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LAYERED,
                        g_lpszClassName, NULL, WS_THICKFRAME,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,
                        _WPModule.GetHInstance(), NULL);

BOOL result = SetWindowDisplayAffinity(m_hWnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);

// do bitblt stuff
```

Comment: it showed as black blank area in the screenshot picture,is there anyother way to make it like totally transparent in the screenshots?

Comment: @Jason117 make sure you have a compatible windows version

Comment: @AsPas what VS / SDK version do I need to avoid the `'WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE': undeclared identifier` error ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to set your window to transparent (with a value of 0 in the `bAlpha` parameter, and a `LWA_ALPHA` flag) before capturing, and return it to opaque (with a value of 255 in the `bAlpha` parameter) afterwards.

The window will flicker a bit, but will not appear in the capture.